# Smoothing of piecewise Euclidean Riemannian metrics

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geometry, triangulations

Let $M$ be a smooth closed manifold and $T$ be a triangulation of $M$. Endow each simplex of $T$ with the Euclidean metric making it a regular simplex; this gives a piecewise Euclidean metric $g_0$ on $M$, which is singular on (part of) the codimension $2$ skeleton of $T$.

Is it possible to approximate $g_0$ by a smooth Riemannian metric? The approximation should in particular change length of curves and the volume by arbitrarily small amounts.

I guess the answer is positive and well-known, but I did manage to find a reference (in particular, several works ask the smoothing to satisfy certain curvature assumptions, which I do not). Is there a reference or are there obstruction to smoothing?

Comment: You need to assume that $M$ is smooth and $T$ is a smooth triangulation: not every PL manifold has a smooth structure. As for your question, Ontaneda had to address similar issues in sections 7-8 of http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1110.6374

Comment: @Igor Belegradek: thanks, I did thought about smooth manifold only, but forgot to write it. Now edited. As for the triangulation, any assumption that does not prevent it to exist is fine.

Comment: Thanks also for the reference, I'll definitely have a look at it.

Comment: @Benoît, what I meant is even if $M$ is smooth it may be that your triangulation is non-smoothable or has a smoothing of $M$ that is different from the original one. Thurston in [Three-dimensional geometry and topology, Princeton Mathematical Series, 35] discusses the issue (around page 197, if memory serves) and sketches that any low-dimensional PL manifold is smoothable by a direct geometric argument. This would be a starting point, and then one would have smooth the metric, but without matching the smoothing with the original smooth structure on $M$ there is no way to proceed.

Comment: You cannot change lengths by arbitrarily small amounts, even in the 2-dimensional case. Consider a cone singularity and a loop near the apex wrapping many times around it.


Comment: @Sergei Ivanov: I don't quite get your example. First, I do not see why the number of times the loop wraps around the apex is relevant. Second, if one has very large curvature at the apex for the smoothed metric, then all kind of length for this curve can happen, so I do not see the obstruction. Note that I am ok with modifications by an arbitrarily small *additive* amount.

Comment: @Igor Belegradek: as I said, I am ok with any assumption on the triangulation, so let it be smooth.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I was wondering whether you have been able to find a reference or a solution to your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Such results are known for surfaces. I believe the correct reference is 
MR0126778 
Rešetnjak, Ju. G.
Isothermal coordinates on manifolds of bounded curvature. I, II. (Russian) 
Sibirsk. Mat. Ž. 1 1960 88–116, 248–276.

There are also two books of A. D. Aleksandrov and V. A. Zalgaller, and more recent
survey of Reshetnyak in the Springer Encyclopaedia MR1263963.